# How to limit the number of threads which perform an action in C++ AMP

Tags: c++, c++-amp

I am performing a series of calculations on a large number of threads using C++ AMP.   The last step of the calculation though is to prune the result but only for a limited number of threads.   For example, if the result of the calculation is below a threshold, then set the result to 0 BUT only do this for a maximum of X threads.    Essentially this is a shared counter but also a shared conditional check.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does it matter which X results are zeroed out? For example do you want to remove the X lowest values or is removing any X values below the threshold acceptable?

Comment: It doesn't matter.    I want to zero out the first X results below the threshold.   "First" meaning the first threads that happen to reach that decision point.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your question is the following pseudo-code performed by each thread:

```cpp
auto result = ...
if(result < global_threshold)  // if the result of the calculation is below a threshold
    if(global_counter++ < global_max)  // for a maximum of X threads
        result = 0;  // then set the result to 0 
store(result);
```

I then further assume that both `global_threshold` and `global_max` does not change during the computation (i.e. between `parallel_for_each` start and finish) - so the most elegant way to pass them is through lambda capture.

On the other hand, `global_counter` clearly changes value, so it must be located in modifiable memory shared across all threads, effectively being `array<T,N>` or `array_view<T,N>`. Since the threads incrementing this object are not synchronized, the operation would need to be performed using atomic operation.

The above translates to the following C++ AMP code (I'm using Visual Studio 2013 syntax, but it is easily back-portable to Visual Studio 2012):

```
std::vector<int> result_storage(1024);
array_view<int> av_result{ result_storage };

int global_counter_storage[1] = { 0 };
array_view<int> global_counter{ global_counter_storage };

int global_threshold = 42;
int global_max = 3;

parallel_for_each(av_result.extent, [=](index<1> idx) restrict(amp)
{
    int result = (idx[0] % 50) + 1; // 1 .. 50
    if(result < global_threshold)
    {
        // assuming less than INT_MAX threads will enter here
        if(atomic_fetch_inc(&global_counter[0]) < global_max)
        {
            result = 0;
        }
    }
    av_result[idx] = result;
});

av_result.synchronize();

auto zeros = count(begin(result_storage), end(result_storage), 0);
std::cout << "Total number of zeros in results: " << zeros << std::endl
    << "Total number of threads lower than threshold: " << global_counter[0]
    << std::endl;
```

Comment: I like it.  Thanks Lukasz.    Since only a small portion of results will in general be less than the global_threshold, there will only be a few threads that execute the atomic operation.  And the "key" part is that of still letting those threads increment the global counter but then checking the fetched result afterwards.   I was limited in my thinking that I thought I had to only increment the global counter iff I was going to set the result to 0;    Thanks again.

Comment: Good answer. The other alternatives you could consider here are: Doing this on the CPU if you are going to copy the final results back there anyway, this might be faster. Using a scan followed by a map to zero out the first N values that fail to meet the threshold. This is a lot more code and may, or may not be more efficient.